# AWS codecommit - take actions for PR events

Tags: webhooks, pull-request, aws-codecommit

I'm trying to find a way to send PR events from amazon codecommit. I have a CI solutions and I want to kick off builds for PRs when they are opened/modified.

I don't see a way to do that under triggers :

[image]

But it seems strange as I do see PR events under notifications

[image]

Is there a way to create webhook events for PRs?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the Triggers feature of CodeCommit, I suggest looking at their integration with CloudWatch Events.

Among other things, you can create notifications / trigger workflows for the following actions:

1. pull request created
2. pull request source branch updated
3. pull request merge status updated

Basically, you create a CloudWatch Event Rule with some filters for the action types you want, then choose which service(s) you want to deliver notifications to when those events happen, such as CodeBuild or Lambda.

Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/monitoring-events.html